# Как сделать задержку прыжка в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет) Создаю свою игру на юнити в 2Д, пытаюсь сделать задержку прыжка(допустим если персонаж сходит с платформы, то у него есть немного времени, чтобы нажать прыжок и он сработал бы), но в процессе написания кода у меня появились 2 взаимозаменяемые проблемы:

1. Либо персонаж может сделать двойной прыжок, если очень быстро нажать 2 раза на кнопку прыжка(как я понял это как раз из за времени задержки)
2. Либо задержка прыжка не работает в принципе и персонаж выполняет обычный прыжок и если он уже не на земле, то просто падает, без возможности прыгнуть

Вот 2 примера моего кода:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using TMPro.EditorUtilities;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody2D;
    
        private float _movementAcceleration = 65;
        private float _maxMovementSpeed = 12;
        private float _groundLinearDrag = 10;
        private float _horizontalDirection;
    
        private float _jumpForce = 20f;
        [SerializeField] private LayerMask _groundLayer;
        private float _groundRaycastLength = 0.65f;
        private bool _onGround;
        [SerializeField] private Vector3 _groundRaycastOffset;
        private bool _canJump => _jumpBufferCounter > 0f && (_hangTimeCounter > 0f && _aviableJumps > 0);
        private float _airLinearDrag = 2.5f;
        private float _fallMultiplier = 8f;
        private float _lowJumpFallMultiplier = 3f;
        private int _jumpsValue = 1;
        private int _aviableJumps;
        private float _hangTime = 0.2f;
        private float _hangTimeCounter;
        private float _jumpBufferLength = 0.1f;
        private float _jumpBufferCounter;
    
        [SerializeField]private Vector3 _edgeRaycastOffset;
        [SerializeField]private Vector3 _innerRaycastOffset;
        private float _topRaycastLength = 0.85f;
        private bool _canCornerCorrect;
    
        private bool _changingDirection =>
            (_rigidbody2D.velocity.x > 0f && _horizontalDirection < 0f) || (_rigidbody2D.velocity.x < 0f && _horizontalDirection > 0f);
    
        private void Start()
        {
            _rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }
    
        private void Update()
        {
            _horizontalDirection = GetInput().x;
    
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                _jumpBufferCounter = _jumpBufferLength;
            }
            else
            {
                _jumpBufferCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
    
            if (_canJump && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                Jump();
            }
        }
    
        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            CheckCollisions();
            MoveCharacter();
    
            if (_onGround)
            {
                ApplyGroundLinearDrag();
                _hangTimeCounter = _hangTime;
                _aviableJumps = _jumpsValue;
            }
            else
            {
                ApplyAirLinearDrag();
                FallMultiplier();
                _hangTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
    
            if (_canCornerCorrect)
            {
                CornerCorrect(_rigidbody2D.velocity.y); 
            }
        }
    
        private Vector2 GetInput()
        {
            return new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        }
    
        private void MoveCharacter()
        {
            _rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(_horizontalDirection, 0f) * _movementAcceleration);
    
            if (Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody2D.velocity.x) > _maxMovementSpeed)
            {
                _rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(_rigidbody2D.velocity.x) * _maxMovementSpeed, _rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
            }
        }
    
        private void Jump()
        {
            _hangTimeCounter = 0f;
            _jumpBufferCounter = 0f;
    
            if (!_onGround && _hangTime < 0)
            {
                _aviableJumps--;
            }
    
            if (_aviableJumps > 0)
            {
                _rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidbody2D.velocity.x, 0f);
                _rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * _jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
        }
    
        private void FallMultiplier()
        {
            if (_rigidbody2D.velocity.y < 0)
            {
                _rigidbody2D.gravityScale = _fallMultiplier;
            }
            else if (_rigidbody2D.velocity.y > 0 && !Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                _rigidbody2D.gravityScale = _lowJumpFallMultiplier;
            }
            else
            {
                _rigidbody2D.gravityScale = 1f;
            }
        }
    
        private void CheckCollisions()
        {
            _onGround = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + _groundRaycastOffset, Vector2.down, _groundRaycastLength, _groundLayer) ||
            Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position - _groundRaycastOffset, Vector2.down, _groundRaycastLength, _groundLayer);
    
            _canCornerCorrect = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + _edgeRaycastOffset, Vector2.up, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer) &&
                !Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset, Vector2.up, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer) ||
                Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position - _edgeRaycastOffset, Vector2.up, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer) &&
                !Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset, Vector2.up, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer);
        }
    
        private void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + _groundRaycastOffset, transform.position + _groundRaycastOffset + Vector3.down * _groundRaycastLength);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position - _groundRaycastOffset, transform.position - _groundRaycastOffset + Vector3.down * _groundRaycastLength);
    
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + _edgeRaycastOffset, transform.position + _edgeRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position - _edgeRaycastOffset, transform.position - _edgeRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset, transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset, transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
    
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength,
                            transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength + Vector3.left * _topRaycastLength);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength,
                            transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength + Vector3.right * _topRaycastLength);
        }
    
        private void ApplyGroundLinearDrag()
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(_horizontalDirection) < 0.4f || _changingDirection)
            {
                _rigidbody2D.drag = _groundLinearDrag;
            }
            else
            {
                _rigidbody2D.drag = 0f;
            }
        }
    
        private void ApplyAirLinearDrag()
        {
            _rigidbody2D.drag = _airLinearDrag;
        }
    
        private void CornerCorrect(float yVelocity)
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength, Vector3.left, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer);
    
            if(hit.collider != null)
            {
                float newPosition = Vector3.Distance(new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, 0f) + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength, 
                    transform.position - _edgeRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + newPosition, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                _rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidbody2D.velocity.x, yVelocity);
                return;
            }
    
            hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength, Vector3.right, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer );
    
            if(hit.collider != null)
            {
                float newPosition = Vector3.Distance(new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, 0f) + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength,
                    transform.position + _edgeRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - newPosition, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                _rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidbody2D.velocity.x, yVelocity);
            }
        }
    }
```

Второй вариант не очень, так как в нем я как раз таки пытаюсь пофиксить баг с двойным прыжком, поэтому он неаккуратный и в нем многовато лишнего)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro.EditorUtilities;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody2D;

    private float _movementAcceleration = 65;
    private float _maxMovementSpeed = 12;
    private float _groundLinearDrag = 10;
    private float _horizontalDirection;

    private float _jumpForce = 20f;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask _groundLayer;
    private float _groundRaycastLength = 0.65f;
    private bool _onGround;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _groundRaycastOffset;
    private bool _canJump => _jumpBufferCounter > 0f && (_hangTimeCounter > 0f && _aviableJumps > 0);
    private float _airLinearDrag = 2.5f;
    private float _fallMultiplier = 8f;
    private float _lowJumpFallMultiplier = 3f;
    private int _jumpsValue = 1;
    private int _aviableJumps;
    private float _hangTime = 0.2f;
    private float _hangTimeCounter;
    private float _jumpBufferLength = 0.1f;
    private float _jumpBufferCounter;

    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _edgeRaycastOffset;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _innerRaycastOffset;
    private float _topRaycastLength = 0.85f;
    private bool _canCornerCorrect;

    private bool _changingDirection =>
        (_rigidbody2D.velocity.x > 0f && _horizontalDirection < 0f) || (_rigidbody2D.velocity.x < 0f && _horizontalDirection > 0f);

    private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _horizontalDirection = GetInput().x;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            _jumpBufferCounter = _jumpBufferLength;
        }
        else
        {
            _jumpBufferCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (_canJump && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && _hangTimeCounter > 0)
        {
            if (_aviableJumps > 0)
            {
                Jump();
            }

            _aviableJumps--;
            _hangTimeCounter = 0f;
        }

        if (_aviableJumps > 0 && _hangTimeCounter > 0)
        {
            _hangTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CheckCollisions();
        MoveCharacter();

        if (_onGround)
        {
            ApplyGroundLinearDrag();
            _hangTimeCounter = _hangTime;
            _aviableJumps = _jumpsValue;
        }
        else
        {
            ApplyAirLinearDrag();
            FallMultiplier();
        }

        if (_canCornerCorrect)
        {
            CornerCorrect(_rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        }
    }

    private Vector2 GetInput()
    {
        return new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    }

    private void MoveCharacter()
    {
        _rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(_horizontalDirection, 0f) * _movementAcceleration);

        if (Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody2D.velocity.x) > _maxMovementSpeed)
        {
            _rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(_rigidbody2D.velocity.x) * _maxMovementSpeed, _rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        if (_aviableJumps > 0 && _hangTimeCounter > 0)
        {
            _rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidbody2D.velocity.x, 0f);
            _rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * _jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

    }

    private void FallMultiplier()
    {
        if (_rigidbody2D.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            _rigidbody2D.gravityScale = _fallMultiplier;
        }
        else if (_rigidbody2D.velocity.y > 0 && !Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            _rigidbody2D.gravityScale = _lowJumpFallMultiplier;
        }
        else
        {
            _rigidbody2D.gravityScale = 1f;
        }
    }

    private void CheckCollisions()
    {
        _onGround = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + _groundRaycastOffset, Vector2.down, _groundRaycastLength, _groundLayer) ||
        Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position - _groundRaycastOffset, Vector2.down, _groundRaycastLength, _groundLayer);

        _canCornerCorrect = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + _edgeRaycastOffset, Vector2.up, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer) &&
            !Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset, Vector2.up, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer) ||
            Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position - _edgeRaycastOffset, Vector2.up, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer) &&
            !Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset, Vector2.up, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;

        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + _groundRaycastOffset, transform.position + _groundRaycastOffset + Vector3.down * _groundRaycastLength);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position - _groundRaycastOffset, transform.position - _groundRaycastOffset + Vector3.down * _groundRaycastLength);

        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + _edgeRaycastOffset, transform.position + _edgeRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position - _edgeRaycastOffset, transform.position - _edgeRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset, transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset, transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);

        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength,
                        transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength + Vector3.left * _topRaycastLength);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength,
                        transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength + Vector3.right * _topRaycastLength);
    }

    private void ApplyGroundLinearDrag()
    {
        if (Mathf.Abs(_horizontalDirection) < 0.4f || _changingDirection)
        {
            _rigidbody2D.drag = _groundLinearDrag;
        }
        else
        {
            _rigidbody2D.drag = 0f;
        }
    }

    private void ApplyAirLinearDrag()
    {
        _rigidbody2D.drag = _airLinearDrag;
    }

    private void CornerCorrect(float yVelocity)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position - _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength, Vector3.left, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            float newPosition = Vector3.Distance(new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, 0f) + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength,
                transform.position - _edgeRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + newPosition, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            _rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidbody2D.velocity.x, yVelocity);
            return;
        }

        hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + _innerRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength, Vector3.right, _topRaycastLength, _groundLayer);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            float newPosition = Vector3.Distance(new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, 0f) + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength,
                transform.position + _edgeRaycastOffset + Vector3.up * _topRaycastLength);
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - newPosition, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            _rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidbody2D.velocity.x, yVelocity);
        }
    }
}
```

Пробовал создавать дополнительные проверки, например, что чтобы задержка работала я делал проверку на то, чтобы переменная canJump была true + jumpsValue > 0 + hangTimeCounter > 0, но даже с такими проверками персонаж может прыгнуть дважды, если очень быстро нажать на прыжок

Так же я заметил, что по какой то причине доступные прыжки отнимаются не сразу, а только после повторного нажатия прыжка, каким бы способом я не вычитал, но если вычитать прыжки перед прыжком, то персонаж просто не прыгнет(что логично, потому что прыжков сразу станет 0)

Помогите пожалуйста,никак не могу разобраться как пофиксить данный баг(

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы использовать _jumpBufferCounter, можете использовать состояние прыжка, для отслеживания, находится персонаж на земле, или находится в состоянии прыжка.

Comment: Вы можете использовать не задержку по времени, а чуть больший коллайдер

Answer (score 2):

Ты очень старался хорошо написать класс, следишь за дизайном кода, прилежно изучаешь язык. Твоя проблема возникает из-за того, что у тебя получается `God Class` (антипаттерн), который трудно модифицировать и при попытке начинают возникать ошибки, которые трудно исправлять. Это уже не вопрос языка, а тема проектирования.

Есть `Single Responsibility Principle` (`SRP`), принцип единственной ответственности, первый принцип `SOLID`. Суть просто: один класс для исполнения одной единственной задачи. В твоем классе ОЧЕНЬ много полей, это первый симптом. Как только тебе хочеться разделить наборы полей пустой строкой, не по причине отделиния полей с разными методами доступа, а просто сгруппировать, потому что они не пересекаются, то ты точно нарушаешь srp.

---

Самая частая ошибка, это хардкодить управление в бизнес логику (механику). Должны быть методы, типа `Jump()` или свойства `.MovementVector`, которые задаются управлением из вне. Заменить управление с ручного, скажем `PlayerInputController`, на ai `BotInputController`, у объекта манипуляций ничего не меняется, ему вообще фиолетово, кто дергает за ниточки.

У тебя есть метод `CheckCollisions`, но его нужно вывести в отдельный класс с полем `OnGround { get; private set }`, метод вкл/выкл для отключения после смерти делать не нужно, поскольку у монобехов уже и так есть `enabled`.

Горизонтальное движение влево/право и вертикальное гравитация/прыжёк это тоже две разные ответственности, которые в платформерах чаще даже не пересекаются друг с другом и каждый из которых имеет свой набор полей.

---

Как только ты разделишь свой класс на вышеупомянутое множество, сразу поймешь, насколько легко будет решить проблему с которой ты столкнулся, поскольку она имеет свою чёткую зону ответственности.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое, попробую сделать все более структурированным)